# How many oranges did the litte girl originally have?

Tags: logical-deduction

[image: Question]

Please note: "She never had to cut an orange".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

She started with

> 7 oranges

so she sold to the first customer

> 7/2 + 1/2 = 4 oranges, leaving her with 3 oranges.

She sold to the second customer

> 3/2 + 1/2 = 2 oranges, leaving her with 1 orange.

She sold to the last customer

> 1/2 + 1/2 = 1 orange,

leaving her with none, and no orange had to be cut.

Answer (score 2):

> If she started with $y$ oranges, then this is true:
>  $$\frac{\frac{\frac{y-1}{2}-1}{2}-1}{2}=0$$
>  Then,
>  $$\frac{\frac{y-1}{2}-1}{2}-1=0$$$$\frac{\frac{y-1}{2}-1}{2}=1$$$$\frac{y-1}{2}-1=2$$$$\frac{y-1}{2}=3$$$$y-1=6$$$$y=7$$
>  So she started with $7$ oranges.